# Doctrine 2 difference with tables by one to one same relation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm

I have 2 entities with same one to one relation:

```
class FirstEntity {

...

 /**
  * @var \App\Entity\ThirdEntity
  *
  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ThirdEntity")
  */
 protected $thirdEntity;



class SecondEntity {

...

 /**
  * @var \App\Entity\ThirdEntity
  *
  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\ThirdEntity")
  */
 protected $thirdEntity;
```

`$thirdEntity` field cant be null.
Is there any way to return result by query builder or native query like array_diff() opertion:

```
$firsts = array_map(function (FirstEntity $firstEntity) {
return $firstEntity->getThirdEntity()->getId();
}, $this->em->getRepository(FirstEntity::class)->findAll());

$seconds = array_map(function (SecondEntity $secondEntity) {
return $secondEntity->getThirdEntity()->getId();
}, $this->em->getRepository(SecondEntity::class)->findAll());

return array_diff($firsts, $seconds);
```

So what I want is a list of all `ThirdEntity` that is linked to a `FirstEntity` but not to a `SecondEntity`.

Comment: So what you want is a list of all `ThirdEntity` that is linked to a `FirstEntity` but not to a `SecondEntity`?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i need, is possible by doctrine query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most performant way to do this, is using a native query or the query builder (or multiple native queries/query buidlers). This way, the database will do all the filtering for you, meaning Doctrine doesn't have to do to much work.

The query builder is the easiest way, but does require you to also map from `ThirdEntity` to `FirstEntity` and `SecondEntity` - the following code assumes you have that mapping in place.

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$result = $qb->select('t')->from('ThirdEntity', 't')
    ->innerJoin('t.firstEntity', 'f')
    ->leftJoin('t.secondEntity', 's')
    ->where($qb->expr()->isNull('s.id'));
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

What happens here, is that we ask the database to take all `ThirdEntity` records, `inner join` them with all `FirstEntity` records (so a `ThirdEntity` without `FirstEntity` won't be included). Then we `left join` that with `SecondEntity`, which means that if the `ThirdEntity` is also linked to a `SecondEntity` its data becomes available for filtering, otherwise we get `NULL` for all the `SecondEntity` columns. The last step is to select only those records where there is no `SecondEntity` (meaning its ID is `null`).

Depening on the exact dataset, this "one query" approach may not give you the best performance. It *could* be faster to first select the ID's of all `ThirdEntity` items that have a relation to a `FirstEntity` and then (in a separate query, where you use that ID list as parameter) filter out those items that also have a relation to a `SecondEntity`. It might also be faster to do those two things the other way around. I'm not expecting that though, so we'll leave that for another question (or another answer to this question).